# Is it possible to lift an effect in Scala ZIO into another effectful context?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, cron, zio

I'm looking for a way to lazily compose two effects without first executing their results in Zio. My program takes the following form:

```scala
/**
  * Returns a reference to an effectful singleton cron scheduler backed by akka
  * See https://github.com/philcali/cronish for more info on the API
  */
def scheduled: UManaged[Ref[Scheduled]] = ???

def schedule[R, E, A](e: => ZIO[R, E, A], crondef: String) = 
  (for {
    resource <- scheduled
    task     <- ZManaged.fromEffect(e) // I need to lift the underlying effect here, not access its result
  } yield resource.modify(schedule => schedule(job(task), crondef.cron) -> schedule)).flattenM

def scheduleEffect[A](e: => A, description: String = "")(crondef: String) =
  (for {
    resource <- scheduled
  } yield resource.modify(schedule => schedule(job(e), crondef.cron) -> schedule)).flattenM

// Program which schedules cron jobs to increment/decrement x and y, respectively
def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = {
  var x = 0
  var y = 100
  (for {
    _ <- Scheduler.schedule(UIO({ x += 1; println(x) }), "every second")
    _ <- Scheduler.scheduleEffect({ y -= 1; println(y) }, "every second")
  } yield ())
    .provideCustomLayer(???)
    .as(ExitCode.success)
    .useForever
  }
```

In this current formulation, the decrementing of `y` runs every second until the program terminates, while the incrementing of `x` only runs once. I know that ZIO provides a `Schedule` utility, but for legacy compatibility reasons I have to stick with the effectful singleton used by the Cronish library. Basically `job` takes a pass-by-reference effect of type `A` and suspends it in a `CronTask` for execution within the `Scheduled` singleton according to the schedule defined by `crondef`.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to compose the *effects* themselves, rather than their results in the context of ZIO? I've basically wrapped the legacy cron scheduler in ZIO data types to manage the concurrency properly, but I still need the suspended effect from other ZIO-signature methods in my code to be available for me to pass down into the scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately found the solution by reading through the source code for `ZIO.effectAsyncM`, specifically noting its reference to `ZIO.runtime[R]`:

```scala
/**
 * Imports an asynchronous effect into a pure `ZIO` value. This formulation is
 * necessary when the effect is itself expressed in terms of `ZIO`.
 */
def effectAsyncM[R, E, A](
  register: (ZIO[R, E, A] => Unit) => ZIO[R, E, Any]
): ZIO[R, E, A] =
  for {
    p <- Promise.make[E, A]
    r <- ZIO.runtime[R]         // This line right here!
    a <- ZIO.uninterruptibleMask { restore =>
           val f = register(k => r.unsafeRunAsync_(k.to(p)))

           restore(f.catchAllCause(p.halt)).fork *> restore(p.await)
         }
  } yield a
```

Though I was not able to find a direct reference to this method in the ZIO docs, the Scaladocs were clear enough:

> `Returns an effect that accesses the runtime, which can be used to (unsafely) execute tasks. This is useful for integration with legacy code that must call back into ZIO code`.

With this, my new implementation works beautifully as follows:

```scala
def schedule[R, E, A](e: => ZIO[R, E, A], crondef: String) = 
  (for {
    resource <- scheduled
    runtime  <- ZManaged.fromEffect(ZIO.runtime[R])
  } yield resource.modify({
    schedule => schedule(job(runtime.unsafeRun(e)), crondef.cron) -> schedule
  })).flattenM
```